# Probabilistic Inequalities with Lower Bounds

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Many inequalities (Markov, Chevyshev, Chernoff) give some sort of upper bound to $P(X \geq a)$ for some random variable $X$. I am trying to find some results that give a lower bound to this probability.

I have found [this](https://core.ac.uk/reader/236623940) result, but unfortunately this only holds for $X \geq 0$. Any there any known results that hold more generally?

If it makes any difference, the specific case I'm trying to apply this to has $X$ symmetric and $E(X^n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, but I would be happy to explore any results on this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to look into "anticoncentration inequalities." One standard example is [the Paley—Zygmund inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality).
$$
\forall \theta\in[0,1],\; \mathbb{P}\{ X \geq \theta \mathbb{E}[X]\} \geq (1-\theta)^2 \frac{\mathbb{E}[X]^2}{\mathbb{E}[X^2]}
$$
where $X$ is any non-negative r.v. For instance, you could apply that to $X := Z^2$ for any r.v. $Z\in L^4$ with mean $0$, to get a lower bound on
$\mathbb{P}\{ |Z| \geq \theta \sqrt{\operatorname{Var}[Z]}\}$.

Another one is the [Carbery—Wright theorem](https://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/%7Eryanod/?p=2230), which applies to polynomials functions of a multivariate Gaussian r.v..